# Sets of words from a text file

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, set

I am trying to create a set of words, which means strictly only alphabets from a .txt file. This txt file contain all possible characters, including non-printable text.

No re or collection libraries. Python 3

For example, given a .txt file that reads

```
*eBooks$ Readable By Both Humans and By Computers, Since 1971**

*These# eBooks@ Were Prepared By Thousands of Volunteers!
```

I would need my sets to contain

```
  {'eBooks', 'Readable', 'By', 'Both', 'Humans', 'and', 'Computers', 'Since', 'These', 'Were', 'Prepared', 'Thousands', 'of', 'Volunteers'}
```

Here is what I have done but I am still getting special characters and digits on my sets. I only want alphabets

```
import string
filecontent = []
word_set = {}
with open ("small.txt") as myFile:
    for line in myFile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace("\t","")
        for character in line:
            if character in string.digits or character in string.punctuation:
                line = line.replace(character, "")
            if line != "":
                filecontent.append(line)
lowerCase = [x.lower() for x in filecontent]
word_set = {word for line in lowerCase for word in line.split()}
```

Comment: May I ask why you exclude answers using moduls with proven-in-use methods made exactly for purposes like yours?

Comment: does the order matter? and what about a word like `there's`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Cunningham Good to have and order doesn't matter since its a set

Comment: @Lord_Gestalter It is a requirement of an assignment.

Comment: using python 2 or 3?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 3

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> def solve(s):
        for line in s.splitlines():
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.strip(punctuation)
                if word.translate(None, punctuation).isalpha():
                    yield word
...                 
>>> s = '''*eBooks$ Readable By Both Humans and By Computers, Since 1971**

*These# eBooks@ Were Prepared By Thousands of Volunteers!'''
>>> set(solve(s))
set(['and', 'Both', 'Since', 'These', 'Readable', 'Computers', 'Humans', 'Prepared', 'of', 'Were', 'Volunteers', 'Thousands', 'By', 'eBooks'])
```

If you're using Python 3 then you need to replace the `str.translate` part with:

```
table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, punctuation)) #add this at the top of function
...
if word.translate(table).isalpha():
    ...
```

Comment: you will need to update the translate line for python 3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for the update, added fix related to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the `re` regex module. It also provides a word count, but if you don't want that you can just use the keys, or swap it out for a set.

```
text = """*eBooks$ Readable By Both Humans and By Computers, Since 1971**

*These# eBooks@ Were Prepared By Thousands of Volunteers!"""

import re

from collections import Counter

words = Counter()

regex = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]+")

matches = regex.findall(text)
for match in matches:
  words[match.lower()] += 1

print words
```

Or alternatively, if you have it in a file;

```
with open("fileName") as textFile:
  text = "".join(textFile.readLines()) #Necesary to turn the file into one long string, rather than an array of lines.
  matches = regex.findall(text)
  for match in matches:
    words[match.lower()] += 1
```

Which gives

```
Counter({'by': 3, 'ebooks': 2, 'and': 1, 'both': 1, 'since': 1, 'these': 1, 'readable': 1, 'computers': 1, 'humans': 1, '1971': 1, 'prepared': 1, 'of': 1, 'were': 1, 'volunteers': 1, 'thousands': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you i have used re.findall

```
import re
s = '''*eBooks$ Readable By Both Humans and By Computers, Since 1971**
*These# eBooks@ Were Prepared By Thousands of Volunteers!'''
set(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+',s))
```

output

```
set(['and', 'Both', 'Since', 'These', 'Readable', 'Computers', 'Humans', 'Prepared', 'of', 'Were', 'Volunteers', 'Thousands', 'By', 'eBooks'])
```

Comment: This won't work for words with punctuation, for example: `can't`.